# Spinner not displayed on Kanban Item Drop

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I built a Kanban using LWC and when I drag an item and drop it in a new column then it save my object with a new status

when I handle the update record it takes some time and I would like to add a loading Spinner to make the user understand that something is happnening

I tried my best but I did not get to display it. I added console.log to check the values but they do not appear as well ..
Could you please give me a hand please?

Here is my code:

```
handleItemDrop(event){
        let stage = event.detail
        // this.records = this.records.map(item=>{
        //     return item.Id === this.recordId ? {...item, StageName:stage}:{...item}
        // })
        this.isLoading = true;
        console.log(this.isLoading)
        this.updateHandler(stage)
        this.isLoading = false;
        console.log("is loading", this.isLoading)
    }
    updateHandler(stage){  
        const fields = {};
        fields[ID_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.recordId;
        fields[STAGE_FIELD.fieldApiName] = stage;
        const recordInput ={fields}
        updateRecord(recordInput)
        
        .then(()=>{
            console.log("Updated Successfully")
            this.showToast()
            return refreshApex(this._wiredOppData);

        }).catch(error=>{
            console.error(error)
        })
    }
```

and my HTML look like:

```
<template>
    <template if:true={isLoading}>
        <div class='spinner'>
            <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading"></lightning-spinner>
        </div>
    </template> 
    <lightning-card>
        <div class="card_wrapper">
            <template for:each={pickVals} for:item="item">
                <div class="stageContainer" key={item} style={calcWidth}>
                    <h1 class="column_heading">{item}</h1>
                    <c-drag-and-drop-list records={records} stage={item} 
                    onlistitemdrag = {handleListItemDrag}
                    onitemdrop = {handleItemDrop}
                    >
                    </c-drag-and-drop-list>
                </div>
            
            </template>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `updateHandler` calls a function that has a promise (`updateRecord`) and runs in async mode, due to which the `this.isLoading = false;` does not wait till the that is completed.

Two ways to make it work:

1. Move the isLoading inside promise:

   ```
   this.isLoading = true;

   updateRecord(recordInput)
       .then(() => {
           console.log("Updated Successfully");
           this.showToast();
           return refreshApex(this._wiredOppData);
       })
       .catch((error) => {
           console.error(error);
       })
       .finally(() => {
           this.isLoading = false;
       });
   ```
2. Use [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) to make the code run in synchronous mode.

Comment: Ok understood now, thx for the help I used method 1 and worked